# Does Boost Asio networking send/recieve have any sort of data completeness guarantee?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, boost-asio

I've been using boost asio sockets (UDP and TCP) to handle a custom protocol between my client server program. Its been working great until I discovered that on TCP async_send/async_recieve calls that data can arrived in combined chunks.

For example, if I make two send calls each with it's own packet, they can arrive combined at a single receive call. I wrongly assumed that every send corresponds to a receive, but I'm obviously wrong. It however has worked well for the longest time until I found the issue running the client for a different OS.

So my question is: are there any guarantees to the completeness of the data on arrival for every receive call? (e.g. async_send 128 bytes arrive in multiples of 128 bytes, or how it arrives must always be treated as random, like 1 bytes arrives then 127 bytes is possible)

More specifically, does this mean that:

- Data can arrive concatenated or partial for every send call, and I
  have to **always** handle the concatenated/partial data manually
- Is this true for both UDP and TCP asio sockets?

I searched around and couldn't find any documentation on this so I was wondering if anyone have any idea.

Comment: "if I make two send calls each with it's own packet, they can arrive combined at a single receive call." ----------------How do you say it? have you tracked TCP packets?
"It however has worked well for the longest time until I found the issue running the client for a different OS." ---------- So, I believe you are not suspecting ASIO ,but OS.
"data completeness"-----what do you mean by the word data-completeness? looks like the data sent by server has been received completely, but the only problem is it was combined.

Comment: so for the longest time, every async_send call I make has a corresponding async_recieve call. For example, I can async_send with a data packet of 128 bytes, then on the async_recieve handler end I get the entire 128 byte of data. But it turns out this is not true on in all scenarios, so in the case where I make two async_send calls, each with 128 byte packet, a single async_recieve will get 256 bytes, which requires me split up the data

I'm not sure why it worked as is for so long. This behavior does not occur on non Windows machines, so it must be OS dependent.

Comment: Change your receive buffer size to whichever size you want to receive from a single `async_receive` operation, so no matter what platform you are on, the read is going to be limited on buffer size, apart from that, I don't find ASIO talk (not even close) about your term "data-completeness" in `async_read/write` documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more testing here's what I concluded: the answer is no. Boost Asio sockets does not have magic that can enforce data completeness beyond what the TCP/UDP protocols enforces.

Edit:
So here's more of my research:

[For TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758547/partial-receipt-of-packets-from-socket-c), it acts like a data stream. So packets may arrive partial or combined and is complete. So the user application need to handle deserialization of combined or partial data.

[For UDP](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306071/can-udp-packets-be-glued), because it is a datagram packet, if the packet arrives, it is guaranteed to be independent and complete. So there is no need to handle partial or combined packets.

Comment: TCP data most certainly can split as well as combine.  For example, if 1.5 send calls fit in a single packet, the second message certainly can be split in two.  Reassembly only applies when IP datagrams are fragmented in the network, not for buffering choices in the sender TCP/IP stack.

Comment: I did some quick search and it seems partial TCP packets are indeed possible. I have yet to encounter this which made me suspect the it might be assembled before it reaches the app.

Comment: I agree that splitting probably happens a lot less often than combination (particularly because TCP has a feature, called the Nagle algorithm, specifically designed to combine sends into fewer packets to improve efficiency)

Comment: Post your edit, it means that clumped packets are possible *in TCP.* They aren't possible in UDP. You should delete the strikeouts. They are of no possible interest or further use.

Answer (score 2):

First its important to understand that boost asio socket receive and sends methods just mean that they ordered the underlying network stack to receive or send data. By network stack this could be the windows socket API.

If you are sending data right to the same computer, via so called loopback addresses, the operating system (if there is any) can just "give" it to the listening i.e. receiving program. Thats the scenario where you would be most lucky to get things in order and always complete for all cases.

However if you want you are addressing another computer or because the operating system is in the mood, you will have different behaviour:

TCP was designed that you will get you data **in the order** you have send it. But the chunks or packet size if will be sent differs even on the same connection and is a key feature of TCP. Your OS or hardware network adapter might do some send or receive buffering too, before informing you. However things won't get lost.

**So in short for TCP: You can make sure the data is complete by waiting for a certain point in your data `async_read_until` is just there for this case. Data from multiple send calls might be in one receive or many**

UDP was designed to have a low latency in contrast to TCP, but without its ordering and completeness guarantees. So when you send a UDP datagram i.e. packet, usually the OS and network adapter will try to send it out ASAP. However on the way to the other computer, the internet might loose it, or hold one packet back until the one you send after the first, so that data you send later, could be received later, while you can also get the sent first, later, or might not. But when you receive a datagram it's complete in it self.

**So in short for UDP: Data will arrive in datagram chunks, but some datagrams might be missing, or might arrive in another order than sent. The data from one send might be in one receive, might not, or later**

Comment: And UDP datagrams may be duplicated. I don't understand your final sentence.

Comment: Datagrams are usually not duplicated, but can be lost or reordered. And you wont get either the complete datagram or nothing.